# Java Swing UI elements not updating all the time

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I am trying to make a simple GUI for a few tools that only have a CLI interface. I figured having one window with multiple tabs would be the best way to go about this. The problem I am running into is that some of the UI elements are not being updated when filling in information/making selections. In particular combo boxes have been the biggest pain.

It displays all the options and I can select the different options, but after selecting something the GUI does not always update the combo box to show the new selection. For example it starts off with "1" selected but then I change it to "3", an event trigger sees that "3" has been selected but the combo box still shows "1".

I have tried adding in repaints and validates to the frames tabs and even the combo box itself with no luck of forcing it to update. Any help would be appreciated.

As a note this also happens with some text fields I have as well that display file paths after selecting a file/folder from a file chooser, but not anywhere near as often

```
package com.test.JavaSwing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestSwing_Main {
    /**
     * start here
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Run the GUI construction in the Event-Dispatching thread for thread-safety
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Control_GUI.createAndShowGUI(); // Let the constructor do the job
                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //bad times
        }
    }
}


class Control_GUI extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static TabA tab1 = new TabA();

    public Control_GUI() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        JComponent panel4 = tab1.makeTabPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab Name", null, panel4, "Tool Tip");

        //Add the tabbed pane to this panel.
        add(tabbedPane);

        //The following line enables to use scrolling tabs.
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from
     * the event dispatch thread.
     */
    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tool Manager");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add content to the window.
        frame.add(new Control_GUI(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setSize(700, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class TabA {

    private JComboBox<String> process = new JComboBox<>(
            new String[] {"1","2","3","4"});

    /**
     * empty constructor
     */
    public TabA() {}

    /**
     * Get the values from the text fields and check boxes
     * and convert them into arguments 
     * @return List<String>
     */
    public List<String> toolArgs() {
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

        return temp;
    }

    /**
     * makes the contents of the Tool tab
     * 
     * @return JComponent
     */
    public JComponent makeTabPanel() {
        /*
         * set up panel and define layout
         */
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        panel.setLayout(layout);

        /*
         * define and set up components
         */
        //choose process
        JLabel processLabel = new JLabel("Process:");
        process.setEditable(false);

        /*
         * add components to panel
         */
        panel.add(processLabel);
        panel.add(process);

        /*
         * define positioning of components
         */
        //process
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, processLabel, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, panel);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, processLabel, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, process, 5, SpringLayout.EAST, processLabel);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, process, 15, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel);

        //process dropdown action on select
        process.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String temp = (String) ((JComboBox<String>)e.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
        });

        return panel;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
So I think I figured out the issue, or rather that there is no issue with the code itself. I have tried running this on different computers without ever being able to reproduce the issue. It seems to just be something specific to the version of the MacBook pro I am running. I cannot get it to happen on models newer than mine, but on versions similar to mine or older I can get it to happen. Not sure what actually causes this.

For reference I am using a ~2011 13-inch MacBook Pro

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Any errors or exceptions?

Comment: `For example it starts off with "1" selected but then I change it to "3", an event trigger sees that "3" has been selected but the combo box still shows "1".` - the data in your combo box doesn't contain the values "1" or "3" so I have not idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @camickr updated so you will be able to better understand....

Comment: @cmeinert, the posted code doesn't compile. After I fixed the problems, the code ran but no components were visible on the tab. I got rid of the SpringLayout and just used the default FlowLayout and the label and combo box were displayed. I clicked on an item and the output was the item I clicked on and the combo box displayed the item. So I have no idea what your question is about. Next time post a proper /MCVE/SSCCE. All the code should be in one file (including imports) so that we can just copy/paste/compile and test.

Comment: @camickr updated code pieces and checked twice that they compile. Everything ran for me from code copied, but i am still having an issue with the combo box not updating most of the time.
I guess I should point out that this requires java 8 for correct compile.

Comment: The code is not in one file. I don't want to copy 3 files.